# Alternate way for prettyNum to process faster

Tags: r, types, data.table

I am working on a bigger dataset than I attached below and I need to encode `double` type columns again. I tried to use `prettyNum` in a function called `encoder` but it works really slow on my data. Here is how I tried;

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1453)

sample_data <- data.frame(a=sample(1:1000,100,replace=T),
                          b=sample(1:1000,100,replace=T),
                          c=sample(seq(1,1000,0.01),100,replace=T),
                          d=sample(seq(1,1000,0.01),100,replace=T),
                          e=sample(seq(1,1000,0.01),100,replace=T),
                          f=sample(seq(1,1000,0.01),100,replace=T),
                          g=sample(seq(1,1000,0.01),100,replace=T),
                          h=sample(seq(1,1000,0.01),100,replace=T),
                          i=sample(LETTERS,1000,replace=T),
                          j=sample(letters,1000,replace=T))
setDT(sample_data)

options(warn=-1)

double_cols <- which(sapply(sample_data,is.double))

encoder <- function(x) prettyNum(x*1e4,big.mark = '.')

sample_data[,(double_cols):=lapply(.SD,encoder),.SDcols=double_cols]
```

It works already but I believe that there is a way faster solution,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can be written in a shorter way: `sample_data[,(double_cols):=lapply(.SD,encoder),.SDcols=is.double]`, but this won't make it faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `format` instead of `prettyNum`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(sample_data)

sample_data1 <- copy(sample_data)
sample_data2 <- copy(sample_data)

options(warn=-1)

encoder1 <- function(x) prettyNum(x*1e4,big.mark = '.')
encoder2 <- function(x) format(x*1e4,big.mark = '.', trim = TRUE)

system.time(sample_data1[,(double_cols):=lapply(.SD,encoder1),.SDcols=double_cols])

       user      system       total 
       1.27        0.01        1.26

system.time(sample_data2[,(double_cols):=lapply(.SD,encoder2),.SDcols=double_cols])

       user      system       total 
       0.08        0.00        0.08
```

Comment: note the use of `trim = TRUE` to get identical results

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with `sprintf`. The gain appears significant.

**1. With your Function**

- Code

```r
set.seed(1453)

sample_data <- data.frame(a=sample(1:1000,100,replace=T),
                          b=sample(1:1000,100,replace=T),
                          c=sample(seq(1,1000,0.01),100,replace=T),
                          d=sample(seq(1,1000,0.01),100,replace=T),
                          e=sample(seq(1,1000,0.01),100,replace=T),
                          f=sample(seq(1,1000,0.01),100,replace=T),
                          g=sample(seq(1,1000,0.01),100,replace=T),
                          h=sample(seq(1,1000,0.01),100,replace=T),
                          i=sample(LETTERS,1000,replace=T),
                          j=sample(letters,1000,replace=T))



double_cols <- which(sapply(sample_data,is.double))

encoder <- function(x) prettyNum(x*1e4, big.mark = '.')
system.time(setDT(sample_data)[,(double_cols):=lapply(.SD,encoder),.SDcols=is.double][])
```

- Output

```r
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
       2.75        0.00        2.86
```

**2. With `sprintf` Function**

- Code

```r
set.seed(1453)
sample_data <- data.frame(a=sample(1:1000,100,replace=T),
                          b=sample(1:1000,100,replace=T),
                          c=sample(seq(1,1000,0.01),100,replace=T),
                          d=sample(seq(1,1000,0.01),100,replace=T),
                          e=sample(seq(1,1000,0.01),100,replace=T),
                          f=sample(seq(1,1000,0.01),100,replace=T),
                          g=sample(seq(1,1000,0.01),100,replace=T),
                          h=sample(seq(1,1000,0.01),100,replace=T),
                          i=sample(LETTERS,1000,replace=T),
                          j=sample(letters,1000,replace=T))


double_cols <- which(sapply(sample_data,is.double))

encoder2 <- function(x) prettyNum(sprintf("%.9g", 1e4 * x), big.mark = '.')
system.time(setDT(sample_data)[,(double_cols):=lapply(.SD,encoder2),.SDcols=is.double][])
```

- Output

```r
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
       0.16        0.00        0.16
```